# iOS Storyboards separation & Memory Managment

Tags: ios, memory, storyboard

Couldn't find this quickly and I guess it's a common question, maybe not.

I have an iOS (7.0+) app (Swift), and I make use of multiple storyboards.

For example I have a Login Storyboard an Blog StoryBoard, News Storyboard and a lot more.

All these storyboards have multiple views with lists (TableView) and some plain views for details.

Dont' hate on me for this one, we're using a Hamburger icon (3 line menu icon) to open a nav drawer on the root view of every storyboard to switch between these (except login) storyboards. The menu can be unlimited therefore the burger menu.

So I have this code somewhere which is string based (storyBoard is)

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoard, bundle: nil)
    var controller:UIViewController


    controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController
    AppDelegate.controller!.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Would this cause the previous storyboard to stay alive in memory? Or will it be collected by garbage disposal. I want to know since I have couple of hundred total ViewControllers, and all these resources may stack.

Anyone who can fill me in what I should keep in mind?

Note: I have my controller listed in the AppDelegate, I know this is not a good practice but I just use it for reference and it's set in every baseController on ViewDidAppear so it's always up to date.

Comment: If you keep presenting view controllers on top of each other, then they will stay in memory.  You need to provide more information on how you are managing your view hierarchy, but it looks like you should probably be using a container as your root view controller and asking to to present a new VC - it can then release the old one if appropriate

Comment: In general there is no need to have more than one storyboard. My default answer would be: No, it's not in memory. But that depends online your viewstack and references. So if everything is cleaned up carefully you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Hi as I stated I'm not adding view controllers, I have storyboards with a Navigation controller, which contains the views, when going deeper you can only go back with the back arrow.

I was just wondering about putting up new Storyboards!

Comment: You are adding view controllers by presenting them from the storyboard.

Comment: If different view controllers from different storyboards in the viewstack, all storyboards are loaded.

Comment: Ah Thanks, Maik, so when I instantiate a new Controller on the root and keep no references to the old, it will be collected. That's good news.

I know in general you won't need multiple storyboards but it would get so huge I would get lost. f/e one of our biggest storyboards contains 11 views. We have 8 storyboards for now, which will be more in the future.

Hence it might be a good idea to separate.

Comment: Storyboards don't create overhead, they're just there for automatic UI configuration at our ease @Maik639. There should be no reason to separate as it will create no performance difference. You can if you want to but there shouldn't be any reason.

Comment: If you have three view controllers in a viewstack with three different storyboards every view controller will have a reference (self.storyboard) to its storyboard (pointer to three objects instead of one). So there is a small overhead. In fact I don't know how much data is loaded at all from a storyboard. But there is no need for separate storyboards. My biggest storyboard had about 100 views and that wasn't a problem.

Comment: Oh I'm not doing a separation of storyboards for the memory issue. More because other people will have to work with it, And having that many views in one bord might be a real pain in the ass to actually find where to go, not to mention the amounts of segues going everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 9 / OS X 10.11 / Xcode 7 you can do that with Storyboard-References!

Watch this Video (01:13:00 - 01:14:00):
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=102

Storyboard-References help you to keep your Storyboard simple, clean and separated.

Every iOS 8-Device can run iOS 9. So it could be an option, if you're allowed to upgrade your taget from iOS 7 to iOS 9. (If there is enough time for your app release.)